# Incorporating Material Design without Using Support Libraries

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to incorporate material design into an already existing app without using support libraries. The app will only support this for version 5.0 and higher.

I searched this Stackoverflow and Google, but couldn't find a similar question or tutorial. If I missed it, could you please post the link?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could take the code from the support libraries and write it in your app yourself.

Comment: I've only seen this one: https://github.com/frogermcs/InstaMaterial and there will be a new version of the support library with material stuff, it's just not out yet.